# SwiftUI change the color of image and text inside a TabView tabItem based on selection state

Tags: swiftui

I have a `View` and inside the view i have a `TabView` in `SwiftUI`. Inside the `TabView` exist more than one `NavigationView`. I searched stackoverflow on how to change the color of the tabbar items (image/icon and text) when they are selected by the user and when they are not selected but what i have found does not work. The only thing i have found that works is the .accentColor i am adding to the TabView but this changes the accent color in all the items in the TabView.

I tried also `UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white` at then init but does not seem to work. So is there any way to change the selected/nonselected color of the items (image/icon and text) in a tabbar item with this specific implementation? Below is my code. Any help or suggestion appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import ApplicationCore

public struct TabViewTest: View {
    public init() {
          //UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
    @State var selectedTab: Int = 0
    
    public static let backgroundColor = Color(red: 52 / 255, green: 12 / 255, blue: 4 / 255)
    public static let backgroundButtonColor = Color(red: 235 / 255, green: 220 / 255, blue: 180 / 255)
    public var body: some View {
        
        
        TabView (selection: $selectedTab) {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination"))
                {
                    FeedView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                        .navigationBarTitle("Feed", displayMode: .inline)
                    
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName :"pencil.line")
                    Text("Feed")
            }

            .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
            .toolbarBackground(
                TabViewTest.backgroundColor,
                for: .tabBar)
            .toolbarBackground(
                .visible,
                for: .tabBar)
            .tag(0)
            
            NavigationView {
                Text("Read")
                    .navigationBarTitle("Read", displayMode: .inline)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName :"books.vertical")
                Text("Read")
            }
            .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
            .toolbarBackground(
                TabViewTest.backgroundColor,
                for: .tabBar)
            .toolbarBackground(
                .visible,
                for: .tabBar)
            .tag(1)
}
//.accentColor(TabViewTest.backgroundButtonColor)
}

struct FeedView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
              TabViewTest.backgroundButtonColor.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Text("Nav link test")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Button (action: {
                    selectedTab = 1
                }, label: {
                    Text("go to read tab")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .background(Color.white)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```